# Add static and dynamic data to combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I have a `combobox` and that intilized like so:

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbMarkOfWatch" 
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
          Margin="1" 
          Width="230" 
          MaxHeight="20" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

C sharp

```
cmbMarkOfWatch.ItemsSource = obj.Clock.Select(w => w.mark).ToArray();
cmbMarkOfWatch.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I want to add one static value `All` To the top of the `combobox`.
How I can do it?

Best regards

Comment: what does this return? obj.Clock.Select(w => w.mark).ToArray();

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, and yet one value "All"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
List<string> results = obj.Clock.Select(w => w.mark).ToList();
results.Insert(0, "All");
cmbMarkOfWatch.ItemsSource = resutls;
cmbMarkOfWatch.SelectedIndex = 0;
```